# How can I get abandoned cart collection?

Tags: magento2, abandoned-cart

How can I get the abandoned cart collection on Magento 2? I want to collect it via controller.

Could anyone please help me?

Answer (score 1):

At magento 2.4 works this way:

```
    protected $quotesFactory;
    protected $storeManager;

    public function __construct(
        ...
        \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\CollectionFactory $quotesFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
        ...
    ) {
        ...
        $this->quotesFactory = $quotesFactory;
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        ...
    }
```

At your function:

```
    $collection = $this->quotesFactory->create();
    $store_id = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
    $collection->prepareForAbandonedReport([$store_id]);
    $rows = $collection->load();
    var_dump($rows->getData());exit;//or foreach($rows as $row){...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inject this below code in your construct :

```
protected $reportColl;
protected $storeManager;

public function __construct(
    \Magento\Reports\Model\ResourceModel\Quote\Collection $reportColl,
    \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
){
    $this->reportColl = $reportColl;    
    $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
}
```

and then, use this below code in your function :

```
$collection = $this->reportColl->create();
$store_id = $this->storeManager->getStore()->getId();
$collection->prepareForAbandonedReport([$store_id]);
$rows = $collection->load();
```

**Remove generated and clean cache.**

Comment: Thanks. I will try it. Actually, my requirement is to collect the data and store it as a CSV. Could you please guide me?

Comment: I have tried this code but its not working. Could you please help?

Comment: I need to collect abandoned cart data. If you can share the sample code, that would be very helpful for me